# Angular rxjs mix observable and promises

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs, subscription

I'm developing an Angular app and I use Rxjs, Observables and all the stuff to transfer data from my Data Access Layer to components.

I have a Service which gets Bootstrapping data (named B).
Another service (named A) fetches these data and gives them to a component through a Subject.

My goal is to keep these data in my service A but only when I get the data the first time. So, I will use a Promise.

I need my Promise to "subscribe" to the Subject and then "unsubscribe" directly.

I tried the a BehaviorSubject, A ReplaySubject but the Promise never gets called...

The Bootstrap Service

```
export class BService {
  propsFetched: Subject<BootstrapProperties> = new Subject<BootstrapProperties>();

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { //... }

  init() {
    this.fetchBootstrapProperties().then(
      (res) => {
        // ...
        this.propsFetched.next({ ...res });
      }
    );
  }

  private fetchBootstrapProperties(): Promise<BootstrapProperties> {
    const url = UrlResolver.resolveUrl(UrlResolver.EndPoint.BOOTSTRAP);
    return this.httpClient.get<BootstrapProperties>(url).toPromise();
  }

  getDefaultData(): Observable<Data> {
    return this.propsFetched.pipe(map(data => {
      // Some data computation
      return data;
    }));
  }
}
```

The service which gets data and transfers them to components

```
export class AService {
  sub$ = new BehaviorSubject<Data>();

  constructor(private bService: BService) {
    // This one works, it's used by my component.
    this.sub$ = this.bService.getDefaultData() as BehaviorSubject<Data>;

    // Now, I want to "keep a copy" of these data, ... But my promise never fires.
    this.sub$.toPromise().then(d => console.log(d));
}
```

Module and Bootstrapping config

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    // ...
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: init,
      deps: [BService],
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

export function init(bService: BService) {
  return () => bService.init();
}
```

Comment: Why does fetchBootstrapProperties returns a Promise? Can't you just return an Observable?

Also, with your snippet, you never call init() and the promise is never called.

Comment: fetchBootstrapProperties will be called once, I call the `init()` method at the application bootstrap

Comment: You can use an operator such as [from](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/from.html) to turn a `Promise<T>` into an `Observable<T>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest keeping using Observables. There is the pipe operator [share](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/share.html) that share the result of the observable to everyone subscribing to this Observable. The call is made only once.

```
export class BService {
  public fetchBootstrapProperties$: Observable<BootstrapProperties>;

  constructor() {
    this.fetchBootstrapProperties$ = this.httpClient.get<BootstrapProperties>(url).pipe(
      map(data => {
        // computation
        // return data
      }),
      share()
    );
  }
}

export class AService {
  constructor(bService: BService) {
    this.bService.fetchBootstrapProperties$.subscribe(data => {
      // get your data
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks ! I sorted out the problem the `share()` method and a subscriber